# Enforce Magento module dependencies when running setup scripts

Tags: magento

Magento will consider any declared module dependencies in app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml when calculating runtime configuration values such as rewrites, events, etc. however it does not follow a similar process when sequencing module setup scripts. The setup scripts are executed in alphabetical order, which can cause issues when one module depends on setup scripts defined in a module that comes later in the alphabet.

The relevant code is in `applyAllDataUpdates` method of `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`:

```
    $resources = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/resources')->children();
    foreach ($resources as $resName => $resource) {
        <snip/>
        $setupClass->applyDataUpdates();
    }
```

Is there a safe/preferred/recommended option to ensure that necessary setup scripts have been executed prior to running the required scripts?

Comment: You mentioned on Twitter that the version was 1.5 - updated my answer with complete POC. Check your dependency argument?

Answer (score 3):

I'm curious to know the use case, but I see module dependencies having effect in this area, which is to be expected, as all of the config files are loaded according to module declaration entry + dependency specification.

**POC**

Verified in 1.5.1.1:

*app/etc/modules/a.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foo_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Foo_Module>
        <Mage_Eav>
            <depends>
                <Foo_Module />
            </depends>
        </Mage_Eav>
    </modules>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Foo/Module/etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foo_Module>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Foo_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <foo_module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Foo_Module</module>
                </setup>
            </foo_module_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

`Mage_Core_Model_App`:

```
public function run($params)
{
    $options = isset($params['options']) ? $params['options'] : array();
    $this->baseInit($options);

    if ($this->_cache->processRequest()) {
        $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    } else {
        $this->_initModules();
        $this->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);

        if ($this->_config->isLocalConfigLoaded()) {
            $scopeCode = isset($params['scope_code']) ? $params['scope_code'] : '';
            $scopeType = isset($params['scope_type']) ? $params['scope_type'] : 'store';
            $this->_initCurrentStore($scopeCode, $scopeType);
            $this->_initRequest();
    /*Dump resource node here: */
            var_dump(Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/resources')->children()); die;
            Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();
        }

        $this->getFrontController()->dispatch();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: thx Ben. can you confirm which version? This was observed in Community 1.5.x, sorry should have specified in the question.

Comment: agree with Ben, setups are run in the same order as etc/config.xml gets merged. E.g. in the same way as events, layouts, rewrites, etc. There is no difference.

Comment: Curious whether you've ended up confirming this, Jonathan.